# Assign nested attribute on sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a user model with a nested location attribute. I'm trying to assign an address upon registration. Since there is no place for them to put their address, I want to use the ip address by default. I have the location and ip geolocating working, but getting devise to accept the parameter is the problem.

I've added this to my Registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, location: [ :full_address ]).merge(
        location: { :full_address => request.remote_ip }
    )
  end
end
```

This is the error I'm currently getting
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch
Location(#85361712) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#38238360)

I'm pretty sure it's just a simple issue with my syntax in the merge. I tried

```
location: [ :full_address => request.remote_ip ]
[:location][:full_address] => request.remote_ip
params[:location][:full_address] => request.remote_ip
```

Not really sure what else to try.

Comment: Try `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, location: { :full_address => nil }).merge(
        location: { :full_address => request.remote_ip }` or `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, location: { }).merge(
        location: { :full_address => request.remote_ip }`

Answer (score 0):

```
private
    def sign_up_params
        params[:user][:location_attributes][:full_address] = request.remote_ip
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, location_attributes: [ :full_address ])
    end
```

I decided to go without the merge, and this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use the [`before_create` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in `ActiveRecord`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :location
   before_create :set_location

   private

   def set_location
      self.location.build(full_address: request.remote_ip) unless self.location.full_address.present?
   end
end
```

Comment: This wont work because request.remote_ip is not available in models. That was what I initially had. Thanks though

Comment: No problem - glad we were thinking in the same way :)